# Calling the Date constructor with a Date object

Tags: javascript

The JS documentation for `Date` claims that there are four ways to use the `Date` constructor.  From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date:

```
new Date();
new Date(value); // integer
new Date(dateString); // string
new Date(year, month[, day[, hour[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]);
```

However, there seems to be a fifth way to use the constructor, by passing in a valid date object.  For example, the following works fine in the chrome console:

```
date = new Date() // Wed Sep 02 2015 16:30:21 GMT-0700 (PDT)
date2 = new Date(date) // Wed Sep 02 2015 16:30:21 GMT-0700 (PDT)
```

They are different objects, so it seems like an easy way to make a copy of a date:

```
date2 === date // false
date.setMonth(1) // 1422923421090
date // Mon Feb 02 2015 16:30:21 GMT-0800 (PST)
date2 // Wed Sep 02 2015 16:30:21 GMT-0700 (PDT)
```

So my questions are:

1. Why is this not in the official documentation? Am I missing something?
2. Is this an officially supported use of the constructor? Will it work on all platforms/browsers?
3. Is this a safe way to make a copy of a `Date` object, replacing e.g. `date2 = new Date().setTime(date.getTime())`?

Comment: It works in Firefox, but the result is not exactly the same timestamp as the original one (milliseconds are cut off). Just run the example a few times: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/at51o4aw/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Straight from the relevant portion of the [ECMAScript **6** spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-value):

> If Type(value) is Object and value has a [[DateValue]] internal slot,
>   then Let tv be thisTimeValue(value).

Which basically says that if you pass the Date constructor a single argument and it's an object and it has the `[[DateValue]]` internal slot, then use that to initialize the new object.

So, what you are seeing is documented in the specification.

Here's more detail:

[image]

**But, the ES5 spec is not the same** and will do a conversion to a string when you do what you're doing which will then be parsed as a string by the constructor.  While that will work to preserve everything down to the seconds, it will not preserve milliseconds since those are not present in the default string conversion.  So, if you want a perfect copy, then you should do this in ES5 or earlier:

```
var date = new Date();
var date2 = new Date(date.getTime());
```

Comment: Very interesting... thanks! So is the problem that I've been looking at the wrong documentation? Why does the other documentation not explain this behavior?

Comment: @xph - MDN isn't gospel.  It's a crowd-sourced attempt to help developers (which it does successfully accomplish very often) and I use it a lot.  But, it is by no means always perfect.  All confusion should be resolved by looking at the actual specification.  I don't know why this use of the constructor is not documented there.

Comment: Is this behaviour adopted by all major browsers? Or are they still using ES 5.1 behaviour?

Comment: @MinusFour - I'm not expert on reading these specs, but I think the [5.1 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.2) indirectly covers the same behavior.  Only testing would confirm if they all implement it.  The 5.1 spec says to call `ToPrimitive()` on the single argument.  For an Object, `ToPrimitive()` gets `[[DefaultValue]]` which if passed a number hint, then calls `valueOf()` which returns the internal datetime value from the Date object which is the milliseconds since epoch which when passed to the new constructor will give the same behavior.

Comment: @MinusFour - though I'd certainly say that trying to follow the above path through the 5.1 spec is not easy so it would certainly leave room for mistakes to have been made in implementation though it is common for a Date object to get "cast" to its ms timevalue.  That happens if you just try to subtract two date objects.

Comment: You are right, I didn't thought that `valueOf` would have given a number, so I thought it would have used `toString` instead.

Comment: @jfriend00, actually I just tested it out. The spec says this: `When the [[DefaultValue]] internal method of O is called with no hint, then it behaves as if the hint were Number, unless O is a Date object (see 15.9.6), in which case it behaves as if the hint were String.` Which means `toString()` is actually being called instead of `valueOf()`.

Comment: @MinusFour - I'm still not entirely sure no hint is passed.  But it would still makes the same result even if it used the string version, right?  Perhaps the revision in ES6 is to stop the silly conversion to string that then has to be parsed all right back to the same primitive value.

Comment: @MinusFour - that is bizarre that a Date object whose primitive value is clearly a number would default to providing a string if the primitive is requested with no hint.  Somebody was messed up when they decided that a long time ago.

Comment: Well it kind of makes sense to have the `[[DefaultValue]]` of the Date object to have a default hint of String (Dates are normally represented in a String format). However, I think that constructor spec should have use `toPrimitive` with a hint to Number.

Comment: @MinusFour - dates are only represented as a string when humans want to read them.  At all other times for all other operations, they are numbers.  Oh well, someone had a reason at some point.  I agree providing a hint of number would have made sense.

Comment: @xph - added info about the differences between ES5 and ES6.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against that for now. This is what's going now under the browsers following different specs for the `Date` object.

ES 6.0:

```js
var d1 = new Date();
var d2 = new Date(d1.getTime());
//ES6.0 basically gets the property that holds the timestamp straight from the object.

document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = 'Assert: ' + d1.valueOf() + ' === ' + d2.valueOf() + ' ' + (d1.valueOf() === d2.valueOf());
```

```html
<pre id="results"></pre>
```

It does compare it perfectly BUT.... Here's how ES5.1 will handle that:

```js
var d1 = new Date();
var d2 = new Date(Date.parse(d1.toString()));
//ES5.1 will attempt to parse the string representation of the Date object.

document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = 'Assert: ' + d1.valueOf() + ' === ' + d2.valueOf() + ' ' + (d1.valueOf() === d2.valueOf());
```

```html
<pre id="results"></pre>
```

It basically gets rids of the milliseconds of the first `Date` object (Assertion might work if the first date object has no milliseconds, run the snippet a couple of times). Firefox seems to be following ES5.1 behaviour at the moment and Chrome ES6.0. Can't really say when they started adopting it.

I would definately not advise to pass the `Date` object as a constructor for a new `Date` object if the purpose is to clone the first `Date` object. Use `Data.prototype.getTime()` instead.